# Why does hiding a neighbor element breaking my float left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

I have several of these tabs that I would like to be able to collapse them. I am using a directive to show/hide the content underneath. When I do, the icons seem to move over to the left a little bit for some reason. I checked the margin and padding and both are still set to 0. I am not sure why this is happening.

```
<div class='menu'> <ul>...</ul> </div>
<div class='Content'> // Hiding this changes the float left of my icons under it

<div class='menu'> <ul>...</ul> </div>
<div class='Content'>

<div class='menu'> <ul>...</ul> </div>
<div class='Content'>

<div class='menu'> <ul>...</ul> </div>
<div class='Content'>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post the html/css needed to reproduce the problem? see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Are you required to use floats? If very old browsers are not a concern then flexbox is a better approach.

Comment: I am not required to use floats. I will look into flexbox